# How do I rename a User folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, rename

When setting up my new computer, I accidentally gave my account the wrong name. I was able to amend the name of the user account in the control panel, but the folder the user files are stored under is still named incorrectly.

I know this doesn't really matter, but it is going to drive me crazy none the less.

How do I rename the user account folder (the folder inside `Users`) in Windows 7, without breaking everything?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new account. There are too many places in both the registry and in system files that rely on the folder name staying the same. It is *usually* purely cosmetic for it renaming your account. If you want to change the folder name though without breaking anything, quickest way is to create a new account and transfer your stuff over.

Another way (although untested) is to use Junction Points; however, you will need to reboot your computer with the Windows 7 DVD to enter the recovery program and access the Command Prompt

Comment: Why not a symlink?

Comment: @soandos Cause he would still have the old folder listed as well

Answer (score 2):

If everything that you has been installed correctly, then if you change that folder's name (from a different account), and then change the locations stored in

> `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\ProfileList`

to match the new folder location.

That should point everything that is windows dependant, and most of the application files and settings to the right location.

Programs that for whatever reason hardcoded the path will have to be changed manually (search the registry for the old folder location to find them)

Alternatively (and this is much safer) just create a symlink to the new folder, and have the link replace the old folder

Answer (score 1):

I have used the solution from [Microsoft](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19834.how-to-rename-a-windows-7-user-account-and-related-profile-folder.aspx)
It boils down to following steps:

1. Create temp admin account
2. Log as temp and change user folder and corresponding registry value
3. Remove temp admin account

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked for me like a charm with one exception: Don't select the _Advanced_ tab at 6.c. – it didn't let me change the User Name there. Select _Properties_ right on the _Users_ tab.